# Google Places API for Android autocomplete extract data

Tags: android, google-places-api

Is there any way to extract data like city and postcode from the Place object after I select a place in the autocomplete widget. Currently in onActivityResult I only get the Place object on which I have a method getAddress(). But this returns me just a string...

Comment: add your code also

Comment: Well, I think you need Geocoder API for that..

Answer (score 0):

No. You have To call api forma place details

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity which explains quite clearly how to get the city and postcode.